# Getting "webpage is not found" and "timeout error" on form

Tags: mysql, forms, php

I'm getting an error when I try to submit a form.  But, this only happens if the webpage it idle for 9 or minutes before uploading.  Also, it's sporadic.  It's not every time.
This is in Chrome
[image]

This is in FireFox
[image]

Also, I will occasionally get this error too
[image]

This is my php.ini file:

```
register_globals = off
allow_url_fopen = off

expose_php = Off
max_input_time = 10080

;extension_dir = ./
;upload_tmp_dir = /tmp

precision = 12

memory_limit = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 192M
```

You can see that I have `set_max_time = 10080` aka 3 hours.  The whole framework is scripted fine and totally debugged.  These errors are random and only happen after being idle.  Yet, the php.ini should prevent this.  Sorry I can't provide more info, but are there any ideas on what might be going on?  Thank you

This is at the top of the upload page.  The $_SESSION['user_id'] is already set after the user is logged in.

```
<?php

    ob_start(); // <<<--- WILL THIS CAUSE A PROBLEM???
    session_start();

    include($ap.'/path-to-core-connectionfile...');

    if(!logged_in()) {
        header('location: http://???.com');
        }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> *only happen after being idle*

This could be a session related problem. Some kind of redirection loop when your controller can't find session variables anymore, for example.

Also, have you tried to take a look at Apache error logs?

Comment: I haven't.  I've set it up with hosting, but it won't be active for 24 hours or so.  How could it be session related issue?  I can provide some code, what would you need to see?  Thanks.

Comment: It depends on how you manage anonymous user (when the user come for the first time) on a restricted page. For example, if you redirect them to an error page, which redirect itself to the same error page...

Comment: I've updated the question.  At the end you can see how I have the top of the page configured.  Does ob_start(); mess thing up?  And I see what you mean.  I do have tight security on redirects.  But, I'm not sure how it would result in a redirect loop.  Would that be correlated to web page cannot be found?  There's just so mane things going wrong here and it's all tied to idle behavior.  Yet, the .ini file is properly configured.  I'm not sure how to handle this...

Comment: How would I fix the session related issue.  What would cause the controller to not be able to find it?

Comment: What does `logged_in()` do? Simply test whether `$_SESSION['user_id']` is defined?
The `header()` function send a redirect to the browser. When he come on the new URL, if another `header()` redirect is sent, and so on, he can't find a page, so *This webpage is not available* is prompted.
The server store session variables for a limited amount of time (30 mn by default I think). When he can't find them, he generate a new one. You script should prompt login/password again (or use cookies for example).

Comment: function logged_in() {
  return isset($_SESSION['user_id']);
  }

Comment: I don't have any cookies set I just let the session drag out for how ever long.  So, is the controller just not finding the $_SESSION['user_id'];?  Because when the page is refreshed the user is still logged in.  Would it have something to do with cookies or would I have to manually set something for idle behavior?

Comment: I don't want a manual re-login because the form is a long form and valuable info.  It cant be lost.

Comment: *when the page is refreshed the user is still logged in*. So it is not a session problem. Sorry, without Apache logs, I can't find the issue.