# Getting error when uploading form only if idle for more than 10 or so minutes

Tags: forms, php

I have an form script that has 25 or so text fields and 2 image upload fields.  The script works fine, but if you're idle for 9 or 10 minutes it gives an error where the webpage can't be found or it times out.

See the screen shots from a question related to this I posted earlier:
[Getting "webpage is not found" and "timeout error" on form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625230/getting-webpage-is-not-found-and-timeout-error-on-form)

In my error logs I'm getting this error:

```
[Thu Mar 08 12:11:52 2012] [error] [client 66.249.67.230] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

I'm pretty stumped right now.  I only happens when you're idle for 10 or so minuts.  You can see my php.ini file in the screen shots from the other question.  In there I have `max_input_time = 10080` so I don't know why it would timeout...  Anyway I'm really stumped on this.  Any suggestions?  Thank you

UPDATE -- in response to a comment

```
ob_start();
session_cache_expire(180);
session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you require the user is logged in before using this form? Sounds like your form target script is trying to redirect the user to a login form (or something similar) after the session expires.

What is the session expiration time?

See this: [session_cache_expire](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-expire.php)

Comment: Yes you have to be logged in.  You can see the top of my script at the bottom of the other question.  I'm not using cookies and there's no expiration time.  It only happens if you're idle then submit.

Comment: How does that look?  I updated the question.  Would that be the reason for all of the redirects when it's idle?